# How to pass two value from a link to another page using php?

Tags: php, html

I need to pass two value from a php page to another. I can pass one value but dont know about two.

```
<a href="boardInsert.php?exam=<?php echo $row['year']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

I need to pass another variable called 'year' with 'exam'.

Comment: This was my code..<a href="boardInsert.php?delete=<?php echo $row['year']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

Comment: You can use `&` to separate the key value pairs.

Comment: <a href="boardInsert.php?exam=<?php echo $row['idr']; ?> & year=<?php echo $row['yid']; ?>">Delete</a>       is it?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a much better function to make query strings. It is safer than manually creating it. It is called [`http_build_query`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

You can build an array of values and then pass it through this function when making a html link.

```
$values = [
    'exam' => $row['idr'],
    'year' => $row['yid']
];
echo '<a href="boardInsert.php?'. http_build_query($values) .'">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="boardInsert.php?exam=<?php echo $row['year']; ?>&year=<?php echo $variable;?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: isset($_GET['year'] ,$_GET['exam'])       what is the right way to declare it.

Comment: Declare __what__?